# how to restart a method from its last failure point

Tags: java

I have a method like this:

```
    public void runMethod()
    {
    method1();
    method2();
    method3();
    }
```

I want to call this runMethod multiple times based on an id. However, if say method2() fails for some reason, then when I call the runMethod, it should execute method3() and not try to execute method1() again (which has already run successfully for this id).

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 3):

You could record in a map whether a method has executed successfully or not.

```
private Map<String, Boolean> executes = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

public void method1() {
    Boolean hasExecuted = executes.get("method1");
    if (hasExecuted != null && hasExecuted) {
        return;
    }
    executes.put("method1", true);
    ...
}

// and so forth, with method2, method3, etc
```

Comment: Not really though, he wants to skip the failed one also if I read the question correctly.

Comment: @jschoen Good point, I misnamed the variables to imply successes should be skipped, not fails.  However, the code still works the same way; only fields need to be renamed. EDIT: And now it's fixed.

Comment: I am not sure it would. Basically you only need to track if it was called, not if it failed or succeeded. So it should look more like Htaras answer.

Comment: @jschoen Oops, I see what you mean now.  I removed the conditional block, so now it records only if it has been executed, not how it executed.

Comment: But shouldn't `...` com after you add the entry to the map?

Comment: @jschoen It could, depending on how OP wishes to implement the desired functionality.  More likely so, so I've edited it.

Comment: Thanks jschoen and Vulcan... But I would also like to call method1 again down the line. So, if I put this condition, method 1 will be executed only once, which is not what I want. To simplify, lets say I want to call the same method 10 times, and say the 5 time call failed, then when I call the runMethod again, method1 should execute from the 6th time.

Comment: @Sai I'm not sure I understand.  So if method1 fails, it should be skipped for the *next* execution of runMethod, but then it should be invoked for all calls following the one it was skipped (unless of course it fails again)?

Comment: @Vulcan It is like say a call to method1() is present after method3() in the original code. Lets assume method2 fails, then when I call runMethod() again, method3() should execute(as it is next in line) and method1() should execute only once (not twice).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for some kind of state machine. Keep state of the method execution in a data structure(E.g map).

At the beginning of method, you need to check whether execution of method1 for given id is executed successfully or not.

```
public void runMethod()
{
  method1();
  method2()
  method3();
}
private Set<Integer> method1Executed = new HashSet<Integer>();
private Set<Integer> method2Executed = new HashSet<Integer>();

private void method1(Integer id)
{
    if (method1Executed.contains(id)) {
        return;
    }
    // Processing. 
    method1Executed.add(id)
}

 // Similar code for method2.
```

Comment: The only I would change is the processing comment (which I assume is where the rest of the methods code should go) should happen after the `method1Executed.add(id)`. That is if I am understanding the question correctly, about wanting to skip `method1()` and `method2()` on the second call when `method2()` fails.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my scenario is such that method1 may be called again down the line. And I have 'n' number of methods, each method is basically doing a small step operation. So, if you consider each method as a step, then I may still need to call the same method again, but no step should get repeated, even if it fails.

Comment: id should be added only at the end, because if any exception is thrown in the "Processing " logic, it is not considered success and id should not be added to the "method1Executed" set.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to add an int is an indicator, instead of introducing maps, especially if the code is called often.
It would look something like this:

```
public int runMethod(int flag) {
    if (flag < 1) {
        method1();
        if (method1failed) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (flag < 2) {
        method2();
        if (method2failed) {
            return 2;
        }
    }
    if (flag < 3) {
        method3();
        if (method3failed) {
            return 3;
        }
    }
    return 4;
}
```

Comment: This could get quite messy if more than three methods are being used.